# Custom filter Gmail emails on receiving, mark as important if phrase is found, archive if not

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

We subscribe to a request for information press service, were they send us 15 / 20 emails a day (each with 20 or so queries in them) which are all request from reporters / journalists, asking for an opinion / quote for an article they are working on.

99% of these queries are irrelevant to us, but we have to sift through them to make sure.

We use gmail / google apps for business for our emails i was wandering is there a way that i can set a custom filter to skim through the content in these email, if the phrase/s we are looking for them are not found then archive them but if the phrases are found then mark it as important.

ie. `if phrases 'design, architecture, interior design, furniture' are in the email mark it as important, if not archive email.`

Answer (score 0):

You can, the easiest way I would say is to make two filters using the negative ( - ) sign

example:

Filter 1:  design architecture "interior design" furniture

then mark as important

Filter 2:  -design -architecture -"interior design" -furniture

then archive